# MySQL won't connect to database,nighter create username and password

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a problem with my script it won't create and connect to my database in anyform. Here is my code :

```
<?php
$host="fdb4.biz.nf"
$username="1373217_users";
$passowrd="1234";
$db_name="1373217_users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$passowrd") or die("Database could not connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Database selected could not be found");
$sql="INSERT INTO `members` ('user') VALUES ('$_POST[username]')";

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$sql="INSERT INTO `members` (`username`)  VALUES ('{$_POST['username']}')";


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

This is the login.php and the error it gave me is :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /srv/disk11/1373217/www/tracklist.co.nf/login.php on line 4

Could anyone please tell me why ? 
Thanks.

Comment: where is the connection object and remove quotes for the credentials

Comment: You title does relate to your problem; how do you get to the point that "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" has anything to do with MySQL? You just have missed the semicolon after the first variable declaration: `ost="fdb4.biz.nf";` Please learn how to debug PHP.

Comment: Im suggesting you change `mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$passowrd")` to `mysql_connect($host, $username, $passowrd)` and so on. There is no sence in sending variables in `""`

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error you missed putting semicolon after $host statement  put like this

```
 $host="fdb4.biz.nf";
```

Comment: omg,thank you :))) that was one thing i didn't see.jesus and now i feel stupid... sorry now for this stupid post:)) thanks a lot.

Comment: Cheers and Happy coding. Tick the answer if you feel it is solved for future user reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have putted '(single quote) around `user` also you forgot `;` near `$host="fdb4.biz.nf"`

change this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `members` ('user') VALUES ('$_POST[username]')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `members` (`user`) VALUES ('$_POST[username]')";
```